# TailWind css dist/output.css dosnt contain all classes

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

im generating tailwind output css file and it dosent generate all expected classes
for example tailwind hase up to -16 for margins and padding and it only generates from 1 up to 4 so anything past 4 dosnt work

here is an example of the generated file (only a part of it) :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIXK6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely not asking Tailwind to parse the content of some components. You need to give tailwind the path to all possible .html/.jsx/.vue/.js/.blade, etc... files.

According to Tailwind docs:

> The content section of your tailwind.config.js file is where you configure the paths to all of your HTML templates, JavaScript components, and any other source files that contain Tailwind class names.

So kindly check if your content configuration is setup to scan all necessary files in your template.

For example, if the component you're working on is in this path, `components/forms/buttons/primary.jsx`, then your Tailwind  content section should be like this:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{html,js,php,vue}',
    './components/**/**/*.{html,js,php,vue}',
  ],
  // other config options here...
}
```

Key in layman terms:

```
    /** refers to any directory
    
    /* refers to any file

The last bit containing html, js, php, vue are file extensions to specify what kind of files to scan.
```

You can do same for all other paths where you want Tailwind to build classes from. The asterisks key above should guide you on how to properly reference file paths in the config. Should work!

Comment: i did add all my content paths to tailwind css

Comment: apearently i was missing the " --watch" in " npx tailwindcss -i ./css/style.css -o ./dist/output.css " command so it was only gereated once and didnt regenerate the new output css thus it didnt find the new classes . Thank you for your time

Comment: Ah! Great! You have to watch if you're manually building. Cheers!